# How to use UNION Operator within the calculated field in Tableau.

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I'm looking to union two values from different tables into one result table. something like this. Thanks

```
 if [LossRsvAmt] > 0 OR [ClaimStatus] = 'Subrogation'  then [ClaimStatus]
 union 
 if [Subrogation inventory] = 1 then 'Subrogation Inventory'
 end
```

Comment: Try to use a custom SQL query https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/customsql.html for union in Calculated field

Comment: You're mixing concepts. That's not how Unions work. You could  try changing the words "union if" to "elseif"